# IIS7 doesn't see my default document - HTTP Error 403.14

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-server, configuration

I keep getting an HTTP Error 403.14 when I browse to `http://localhost/`. According to MSDN this is a problem with the default document setting, and the configuration doesn't allow a directory listing.

However, when I specifically pull up `http://localhost/default.aspx` it works fine -- and default.aspx is listed as a default document in my server configuration.

Is there something else that can cause this problem?

---

I've checked the applicationHost.config file:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
          <section name="asp" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
          <section name="caching" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
          <section name="cgi" overrideModeDefault="Deny" />
          <section name="defaultDocument" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
          <section name="directoryBrowse" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
```

and it's listed before directoryBrowse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I was looking in the wrong place -- the default.aspx entry was there at the server level, but the specific website didn't have one set.

Comment: Great, glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to the default-document module of IIS, firstly make sure this module is installed.If it is installed, it could be that it is listed after the DirectoryListing module  in the applicationhost.config file of IIS, it needs to be listed before te DirectoryListing module.